# How to set a static IP for a HoloLens 2 without Wifi

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I have a situation where I need to set a static IP address for a HoloLens 2 for a network that I am wired to through an Ethernet to USB-C dongle. The network is not using DHCP. The HoloLens 2 is provisioned to be an offline secure HoloLens (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-common-scenarios-offline-secure), so there is never the option of connecting to the target network wirelessly. I can only find options to set static IPs for the HoloLenses through the device portal if the network is available wirelessly. Even the Ethernet IP configuration settings are tied to specific network profiles and these profiles only show up for wireless networks.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for setting a static IP for an Ethernet connection is now supported in the New Settings app. This New Settings app is available in the Beta Channel of the Insider Preview program as well as the official release [Windows Holographic version 21H1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-21h1). If the needed release does not appear when checking for updates on the HoloLens 2, the latest release can be manually downloaded from https://aka.ms/hololens2download and installed with the Advanced Recovery Companion (ARC) tool.

Answer (score 0):

The USB-C Ethernet adapter settings are available in HoloLens OS Insider version currently. Please check out this reference: [New Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-insider#new-settings-app)

> Network & Internet:
>
> - USB-C Ethernet adapters will now appear in Network & Internet.
> - USB-C Ethernet adapter settings are now available, including its IP address.

[Start receiving Insider builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-insider#start-receiving-insider-builds) if you want to have a try.

Comment: Thank you. I've added my own answer with information that the feature is now available in the latest official releases.